# Traversing a tree with references with only to each node's children

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a node object with each node having a reference to a vector of it's children. I'm having trouble figuring out how I would traverse the tree and set a "displayed" boolean to true if it meets certain conditions. I was thinking I should utilize a queue but I'm not sure exactly how.

This is the node class

```
class Tag {
public:
enum TAGNAME {
    HTML, HEAD, BODY, TITLE, DIV, P, BR, SPAN, CONTENT
};

std::vector<Tag*> _children;
const std::string _name;
const std::string _id;
std::string _content;
const TAGNAME _tagname;
bool _displayed;

// Must create tags with the tag name and ID upfront.
Tag(const std::string& name, const std::string& id = "") : _name(name), _id(id), _content(""), _tagname(TAGNAME::CONTENT), _displayed(false) {}
Tag(const std::string& name, const TAGNAME& tagname, const std::string& id = "") : _name(name), _id(id), _content(""), _tagname(tagname), _displayed(false) {}
};
```

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Check this out: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/

Comment: That is for a binary tree, but my Tag's can have more than 2 children. This is where I"m having trouble; traversing through each child.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is usually the easiest way to traverse a tree.  Something like this:

```
void check_all(Tag& tag) {
    // ... check conditions and set _displayed
    for (Tag* child : tag._children) {
        check_all(*child);
    }
}
```